# geom_bar summarizes y-values: Can this be changed?

Tags: r, ggplot2, bar-chart

I am struggling a bit with the creating a bar-chart in R. My data looks something like this:

```
   country    x    y
 1 US        10   45  
 2 US        10   67  
 3 GB        50   32
 4 GB        50   11
```

Note that observations from the same country have the same value on x.

I want to compare the values of x between countries in a bar-chart with one bar for each country and the corresponding x-value. However, my problem is that the following code summarizes the values of x. So instead of displaying the US-bar with a value of 10, it summarizes the two observations and gives the bar a value of 20. The samle goes for GB: It displays a value of 100 instead of 50.

```
ggplot(data = data_joined,
       mapping = aes(x = country,
                     y = x)) + 
  geom_bar(stat = "identity")
```

How can I easily change this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ggplot2` wants to plot one thing per row in the dataset, so if you have duplicated data, it's going to plot it twice.  The default is to stack the values, so that's why things get doubled.

You could ask to overplot the bars using

```
ggplot(data = data_joined,
        mapping = aes(x = country,
                      y = x)) + 
   geom_col(position="identity")
```

but it's probably more sensible to use a dataset which doesn't have duplicated data.  From the name I'd guess you got the dups when you joined two data frames; so use the data frame before joining, instead of the joined one.  Or just select one observation per group, e.g.

```
df <- data_joined %>% group_by(country) %>% filter(row_number() == 1)
```

and then use `df` as `data` in the bar plot.

Comment: Thanks. It worked flawlessly. And you are absolutely correct. I am using a joined dataframe as the original one contains more countries than the joined one.

geom_col did the job. However, after asking Google, I still dont get what exactly the different between bar and col is?

Comment: The help page for both `geom_bar` and `geom_col` is the same: you can read it using `?geom_bar`.  It explains the difference:  for your purpose, `geom_col` is the right function to use, because it's for plotting raw data.  You can get `geom_bar` to do that using `stat = "identity"`, so it doesn't really matter which you use.

Comment: `geom_bar` with `stat = "identity"` doesn't return the same as `geom_col` with `position = "identity"`. So I guess there must be a difference? `geom_bar` continues to "count" x while `geom_col` shows the right value of x for the country.

Comment: You would need `position = "identity"` with `geom_bar()` as well as `stat = "identity"`.

Answer (score 1):

You can pass the unique values to ggplot:

```
ggplot(data = unique(data_joined[, c("country","x")]),
       mapping = aes(x = country,
                     y = x)) + 
  geom_bar(stat = "identity")
```